# Adding custom column data to extension attribute in magento's default V1/orders API

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api, extension-attributes

I have a custom `delivery_date` column in `quote` table which I want to pass to V1/orders , I have passed this in `extension_attribute.xml` as following ;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_date" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After placing order I am able to see it get and set methods for the same in `var/generation/Magento/Sales/Api/Data/OrderExtensionInterface.php` but in API it is not there.

Are there any extra steps I need to follow.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this column to order table and map it in `module.xml` like this:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Saled\Model\ResourceModel\Order"><arguments>
<argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
<item name="delivery_date"xsi:type="string">sales_order.delivery_date</item>
</argument>
</arguments>
</virtualType>
```

and in `di.xml` add the module name in sequence :

```
<module name="Magento_Sales"/>
```